# Unable to install PySpark on Google Colab

Tags: pyspark, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install PySpark on Google Colab using the code given below but getting the following error.

#### tar: spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

#### tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

This code has ran successfully once. But it is throwing this error after the notebook restart. I have even tried running this from a different Google account but same error again.

(Also is there any way that we don't need to install PySpark everytime after the notebook re-start?)

## code:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null

!wget -q http://apache.osuosl.org/spark/spark-2.3.2/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

This following line seems to cause the problem as it is not finding the downloaded file.

!tar xvf spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

I have also tried the following two lines (instead of above two lines) suggested somewhere on medium blog. But nothing better.

!wget -q http://mirror.its.dal.ca/apache/spark/spark-2.4.0/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

!tar xvf spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

!pip install -q findspark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Any ideas how to get out of this error and install PySpark on Colab?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am running pyspark on colab by just using

!pip install pyspark

and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you so much Harmeet. This is super simple solution. I wonder why so many medium and other blog posts state the long and complex way of installing PySpark when there is so super easy solution exists!

Comment: I am glad it helped :).

Answer (score 2):

Date: 6-09-2020

---

**Step 1 :** Install pyspark on google colab

```
!pip install pyspark
```

**Step 2 :** Dealing with pandas and spark Dataframe inside spark session

```
!pip install pyarrow
```

> It facilitates communication between many components, for example, reading a parquet file with Python (pandas) and transforming to a Spark data frame, Falcon Data Visualization or Cassandra without worrying about conversion.

**Step 3 :** Create Spark Session

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').getOrCreate()
```

Done ⭐

Answer (score 1):

you are getting this error because  **spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7** is replaced with latest version on official site and mirror sites.

Go to any of this path and get the latest version

1. http://apache.osuosl.org/spark/
2. https://www-us.apache.org/dist/spark/

replace spark build version and you are done.
every thing will work smoothly.

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q https://www-us.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.3/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!tar xf /content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!pip install -q findspark
```

Answer (score 1):

I had tried to install in the same way but even after checking with proper versions of spark I was getting the same error.
Running below code worked for me!!

```
!pip install pyspark
!pip install pyarrow
!pip install -q findspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('HelloWorld').getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Hello, I am using the exact same code and it gives the following error:
`RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number` 
Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

I have used the below setup to run PySpark on Google Colab.

```
# Installing spark 
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
!apt-get install scala
!pip install py4j
!wget -q https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-2.4.8/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!tar xf spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!pip install -q findspark

# Setting up environment variables
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-2.4.8-bin-hadoop2.7"

# Importing and initating spark
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("Test Setup").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
```